# GridView has strange behavior with large amounts of data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a web report that uses a `GridView` with a `SqlDataSource` as the data source, and it is crashing for what seems to be large `GridView`s. The web page allows the user to enter a date range, click a "Search" button, and then it does a SQL query based on the dates. I know that the query works and that the dates are pulled correctly, but here is what's happening to cause the crash:

1. The user enters a large date range, and the "Search" button is clicked
2. The query runs, and correctly returns ~4500 entries
3. The user then enters a single day and clicks the "Search" button
4. Program crashes, giving this error message:

> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. **Exception Details**: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   
>   Looking at the stack trace and with a few breakpoints here and there, I'm pretty sure that this is happening before the OnClick method of the button is even called. This has happened to me before on a similar report page that I made a month ago, but I would like to know why.

What is happening here?

I am executing this in debug mode on VS 2008, and I am coding in C# ASP.NET, if any of that makes a difference. Also, I'm not sure what code would help, let me know if I need to edit and post some.

**EDIT** Here is the Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
>      System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded() +2692462
>      System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding) +61
>      System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +148
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]
>      System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +206
>      System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +68
>      System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() +8743895
>      System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) +97
>      System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +63
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +133

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Ok, stack trace added. Also, setting `AllowPaging="true"` stops this exception from occurring in the same situation. I wuold rather not enable paging, but why might this not cause the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, [you have exceeded postdata limit](http://geekswithblogs.net/Vipin/archive/2012/03/05/throwifmaxhttpcollectionkeysexceeded-error-message-when-doing-postback.aspx). I believe you are posting back your entire grid to the server.

Comment: I was afraid that something like this was happening. ok, thank you for the help